# How to return a promise to serverless-http

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

Im attempting to use [serverless-http](https://github.com/dougmoscrop/serverless-http) to deploy an express application to AWS lambda. But my application requires a call to an `init()` function that loads the routes among other things and then returns a promise.

```
const serverless = require('serverless-http');
const Core = require('./core')

module.exports.handler = Core.init(process.cwd())
.then(Core => serverless(Core.Server))
.catch(err => console.log(err))
```

The issue is that serverless-http needs `module.exports.handler` to be assigned to the `serverless` function call and not the promise.

I have also tried this

```
const Core = require('./core')

Core.init(process.cwd())
.then(Core => module.exports.handler = serverless(Core.Server))
.catch(err => console.log(err))
```

but it makes sense that that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah. As Siggy said, there is no way to return a promise directly to the export handler. but all serverless-http does is return a function that wraps the express app in a proxy and accepts the lambda parameters.

So here is what I came up with. Works quite well actually.

```
const serverless = require('serverless-http');
const Core = require('./core')

module.exports.handler = function(evt, ctx, callback) {
  Core.init(process.cwd())
  .then(Core => serverless(Core.Server))
  .then(proxy => proxy(evt, ctx, callback))
  .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: "You can't". But based on the [source code](https://github.com/dougmoscrop/serverless-http/blob/73828e188fdf9564412fec9ea65182b5eec9f1ad/serverless-http.js#L36) of the library it doesn't expect any return value from the `handler`. But you can do asynchronous calls since the [source code](https://github.com/dougmoscrop/serverless-http/blob/bab48728470311bcfc89b1b5e75cc23880857dcc/lib/finish.js#L31) of the `finish` handler shows that it adds an event listener to the response socket.